# How to pass file name with Angular HttpRequest while uploading the file

Tags: angular, typescript, http, request, httprequest

The Angular service uploads a file using Angular's `HttpRequest`:

```
  upload(file: File) {
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'POST', 
      this.SERVER_URL, 
      file,
      { reportProgress: true }
      );
    return this.http.request(req)
  }
```

The HTTP server (running Flask) gets this POST request where I can access the file data using `request.data`. Unfortunately, the file name is not supplied. How can I supply the Angular's HttpRequest `req` with the name of the file (an possibly with other custom data) to be passed along with the file data?

Answer (score 0):

To access the file name you could do something like this

```
    upload(file: File) {
    const fileName = file.target.files[0].name;
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'POST', 
      this.SERVER_URL, 
      fileName,
      { reportProgress: true }
      );
    return this.http.request(req)
  }
```

Comment: But with your approach the file won't be uploaded. We will pass the file name only. How to upload the file and submit the file name with the same `HttpRequest`?